# HP Switch Networking to Ping

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

I have 2 VLANs and 2 Devices connected to a HP 2620 switch.

Both port/interface used is untagged and i have assigned an IP to the VLANs as well.

Example

VLAN 50 - 10.1.50.0/24
VLAN 60 - 10.1.60.0/24

Apparently , when i put Device A into VLAN 50 and Device B into VLAN 60 , they are unable to ping each other.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they can't ping each other, they are on different network, if you want to do that , you need to create son mechanism that do some kind of routing.

The thing is, without routing, the communication only will be able between PC on the SAME vlan, because vlans divide the space into  broadcast domains, in other words, NETWORKS, one vlan means one NETWORK.

On your question, you have 2 networks.

Create one vlan interface 50 with ip 10.1.50.1/24, and one vlan interface 60 with ip 10.1.60.1/24.

Then, one PC on vlan 50, put your gateway on 10.1.50.1, and on the other PC on vlan 60, to 10.1.60.1.

Finally, ACTIVATE IP routing on switch

With that, ping should be succefull.

Comment: From Device A , i can ping Device B Gateway.

Device A IP is 10.1.50.5 , able to ping 10.1.60.254 , but not 10.1.60.5(Device B).

Vlan 50 is setup at 10.1.50.254 /24.
Vlan 60 is setup at 10.1.60.254 /24.

Comment: So in example. Device A is at 10.1.50.5/24 GW 10.1.50.254. While Device B is at 10.1.60.5/24 GW 10.1.60.254.

Comment: You need to activate ip routing on switch

Comment: what do you mean by ip routing?

i have ip route 0.0.0.0/0 to 10.1.50.1

Comment: No, that is a default route, you are sending traffic to there, avoid this. You only need to write on the CLI, "ip routing"

Comment: OMG u are such a god.. thank you man... that works so perfect..

Comment: No problem, nice to heard that works

Answer (score 0):

make some thing like IP Routing in cisco to activate routing between vlans

Comment: This answer could and should be improved. You should explain your answer.